Quartz Scheduler Job Trigger in Waiting State forever
I am using Quartz Scheduler for the first time and I have a problem that I have not been able to solve for a very long time. When using RAMJobStore the job runs perfectly but when I change to Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTx the Triger stays in WAITTING state forever. I am using Quartz 3.x with Sql Server.
My config file:
<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="SchedulingPOC" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="Instance_one" />
    <!-- Configure Thread Pool -->
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="5" />
    <!-- Configure Job Store -->
    <!--<add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" />-->
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="db_quartz.QRTZ_" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL" value="SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS UPDLOCK WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.serializer.type" value="newtonsoft" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.maxConnections" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionStringName" value="AnvilPropertyString" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SqlServer" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true" />
</quartz>

My IJob Class:
using System;
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;
using Quartz.Impl.Matchers;
using Quartz.Listener;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading;

namespace AnvilPropertyManagement.Services
{
    [PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
    [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class JobScheduler
    {
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task StartAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                IScheduler scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

                bool checkWhetherJobExists = await scheduler.CheckExists(new JobKey("job3", "group1"));

                if (checkWhetherJobExists)
                {
                    await scheduler.DeleteJob(new JobKey("job1", "group1"));
                }

                DateTimeOffset dtNow = DateBuilder.DateOf((DateTime.Now).Hour, (DateTime.Now).Minute, 0, (DateTime.Now).Day, (DateTime.Now).Month, (DateTime.Now).Year);

                //First Job
                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MonthlyInvoicing>()
                    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                    .UsingJobData("NextJobName", "SendMonthlyInvoices")
                    .StoreDurably(true)
                    .Build();

                //Check whether the second Job has been scheduled
                bool checkSecondJob = await scheduler.CheckExists(new JobKey("job3", "group1"));

                if (checkSecondJob)
                {
                    await scheduler.DeleteJob(new JobKey("job3", "group1"));
                }
                    
                //Second Job
                IJobDetail job2 = JobBuilder.Create<SendMonthlyInvoices>()
                   .WithIdentity("job3", "group1")
                   .StoreDurably(true)
                   .Build();

                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                   .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                   .ForJob("job1", "group1")
                   .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                   .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
                   .StartNow()
                   .Build();

                // Add  Scheduler Listener
                scheduler.ListenerManager.AddSchedulerListener(new MySchedulerListener());

                // Add Job Listener
                scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(new MyJobListener(), GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals("group1"));

                // Add Trigger Listener
                scheduler.ListenerManager.AddTriggerListener(new MyTriggerListener(), GroupMatcher<TriggerKey>.GroupEquals("group1"));

                //Chain job listener
                JobChainingJobListener jobchain = new JobChainingJobListener("MyJobListener");

                await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
                await scheduler.AddJob(job2, true);

                JobKey jobKey1 = new JobKey("job1", "group1");
                JobKey jobKey2 = new JobKey("job3", "group1");

                jobchain.AddJobChainLink(jobKey1, jobKey2);

                scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(jobchain);
                   
                if (!scheduler.IsStarted)
                {
                    await scheduler.Start();
                }
         
                await scheduler.Shutdown(waitForJobsToComplete:true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

I expected the Jobs to be run but the QRTZ_Trigger table shows STATE as WAITING for ever.

Aside... SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS UPDLOCK WHERE LOCK_NAME = ? only aliases the {0}LOCKS table as UPDLOCK, it doesn't hold a row lock on it as is required for this configuration property. For the T-SQL syntax on Microsoft SQL Server you probably want something like SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK) WHERE SCHED_NAME = {1} AND LOCK_NAME = ? here. Ref: Quartz Configuration Reference.

I would start with reading the documentation on the project's website and maybe follow with the examples available in the repository. The code sample makes very little sense as you have decorated some random, non-job, types with Quartz attributes and you start the scheduler and immediately shutdown it afterwards.
